# How to disable/remove ctags from vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I don't how to remove ctags from vim. Each time I type 'Ctrl+]' it tries to find the tags. I want to map this key for other usage. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't believe you need to remove ctags to do the mapping. I think your mapping problem is something else, not caused by ctags. Please edit your question to show your remapping commands and explain what's not working.

Comment: @AndyLester Thanks! I didn't add any mappings yet. It looks like ctrl-] is something native in vim.

Comment: If you put aside the mappings provided by some built-in plugins like Netrw, *Vim itself doesn't come with any mapping*. Things like `d` or `<C-]>` are "commands", not "mappings", that the user can use at will in custom mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctags is an external program that is not part of Vim. It can't be removed from Vim because it isn't there in the first place.

Vim's various ctags-related commands can't be removed either. If you want to map `<C-]>` to something else then there is nothing stopping you.

This normal mode mapping, for example, will delete the current word when you press `<C-]>`, effectively overriding the original meaning of `<C-]>`:

```
nnoremap <C-]> diw
```

See `:help 05.4` for a gentle introduction to mappings.